# need to show $C[0,1]$ and $R^{\infty}$ is not localy compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

could any one tel me how to show the following? I am not getting any idea, thank you for help.

$1)$ $C[0,1]$ is not locally compact.

$2$) $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is not locally compact where $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}=\{x=\{x_n\}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2<\infty\}$ and $||x||=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: It is useful to know that a normed space is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Martin Simply pleased and delighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C[0,1]$ were locally compact, its closed unit ball would be a compact subset. Try to find a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $C[0,1]$ such that $\lVert f\rVert\leq1$ and  no subsequence converges uniformly —one easy way to satisfy the second condition is to pick a sequence which converges *pointwise* to a function which is not continuous.

Do the same for what you call $R^\infty$. For example, consider here the sequence $(e_n)$ of the «canonical basis vectors»: they are all in the unit ball, yet no subsequence converges.

Comment: Can argue in the following way: suppose locally compact, so open unit ball has a compact neighborhood containing it. now I take closure of the open unit ball that is closed subset of that compact  neighborhood hence compact, but both are infinite dimensional space , so we arrive a contradiction

Comment: @Panu, I don't understand what you are trying to argue there nor the argument!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon >0$.

For 1),  define $f_n(x)= \begin{cases} \epsilon nx & x \in[0,\frac{1}{2n})\\ \epsilon nx (\frac{1}{n}-x)& x \in[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})\\ 0 & x \in [\frac{1}{n},1] \end{cases}$.

For 2) (note this space is usually denoted $l_2$), define $f_n(k)= \frac{\epsilon}{2} \delta_{kn}$.

In both cases show that $\{f_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence. Then note that $f_n \in B(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: All balls are homeomorphic, so there is no need to do the $\epsilon$ thing.

Comment: You are right, I made a balls of that one...